# Google Earth Engine: Region of Landsat Image

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, landsat

I have some manipulation in Google Earth Engine, for example:

```
// Load a cloudy Landsat scene and display it.
var cloudy_scene = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80440342014269LGN00');
Map.centerObject(cloudy_scene);
Map.addLayer(cloudy_scene, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], max: 0.4}, 'TOA', false);

// Add a cloud score band.  It is automatically called 'cloud'.
var scored = ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleCloudScore(cloudy_scene);

// Create a mask from the cloud score and combine it with the image mask.
var mask = scored.select(['cloud']).lte(20);

// Apply the mask to the image.
var masked = cloudy_scene.updateMask(mask);
```

And now I want to export result (`masked`) to google drive using method `Export.image.toDrive`, but I don't known how to specify parameter `region` to meet the same as original image `LANDSAT/LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80440342014269LGN00` is.

Please help me construct this region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's what you're looking for:

```
Export.image.toDrive({

  image:masked.select('B3'),
  description: 'Masked_Landsat_Image',
  region:masked.geometry(),
  scale:mask.projection().nominalScale().getInfo()

})
```

In this case I'm using the image's footprint ( with `image.geometry()` ) to define my export region.

Note that I'm using the function `mask.projection().nominalScale().getInfo()` to derive the scale (resolution) of your export. This makes sure I'm using the native resolution of the image (in this case 30m). You need to add `getInfo` to the function to actually retrieves the integer from the server.
You could also just specify 30 or any other desired resolution in meters.

HTH

---

#### Edit:

Just a visual aid to what I've written in the comment below:

3 Images:

1. Top left corner of original LS image (downloaded from EarthExplorer) - Red 
   indicates `NoData`

[image: Image 1]

2. LS image from GEE on top of original image (GEE image has redish pixels) - You can clearly see that there's still the `NoData` part of the original image which is missing in the GEE version. The thing I would be concerned about is that the pixels don't line up nicely.

[image: Image 2]

3. The top right corner of both images: Here you can see how far the 2 images are apart

[image]

Comment: Thank You for suggestion. I've try to extract B3 as in your suggestion, and result image is very close to original but it still have different dimension (7647x7803 instead of 7671x7811). !

Comment: I would't worry about this small difference. The `.geometry()` function gives you the real footprint of the image, it's all google earth engine has. The difference to what's stated in the metadata are due to small fringes of `NoData` in the original dataset. So when you download the image from GEE, you might have slightly smaller dimensions, but the "real" image has the same size.

Comment: Again, Thank You  for explanation! I think, I should accept this real of GEE.

Comment: If you're happy with my explanation, please consider accepting my answer. Thank you.